# Stick button to outside corner of textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a resizable textarea and a button next to it on the right side. I'm wondering how to get the button to "stick" on the right-bottom-outside corner of the textarea with a 10px space between them.

So far my current Code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <textarea class="form-control">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:10px;">Button</button>
</div>
```

I've tried fiddling around with various float, inline and position css-parameters, but I wasn't able to find the desired configuration.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers, Beejay.

Comment: Since you're using TWBS grid system, you should put the button and the textarea in the same column, then add a margin to create that space.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but like I said  I want the button next to the textbox not below ;)

Comment: Then override the TW Bootstrap stylesheet as: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/2uwDT/31/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/7Dr2S/6/

I made this one as basic as possible and should 100% fit your needs now.

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Button" class="btn" />
```

Comment: Same here, your fiddles comes close, but I don't want the button below, but next to the box. Stuck at the bottom corner

Comment: @Beejay My new answer should be exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Feel free to tweak `left:` to your desired needs.